# Can not connect via sshd on scientific linux 6

Tags: openssh, sshd

I try to connect over ssh to my working machine (in the same network).

The machine is reachable by ping and responds with the password prompt when I try to ssh it. But doesn't accept the password.

I double and tripple checked username and Password as well as restarted the service. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm trying to connect from an Ubuntu machine in case it matters.

Here's the debug output: (exchanged userdata by &&(server) **(client))

```
magu_@ThinkPad:~$ ssh -vvv l_guetg@pc9308
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to pc9308 [129.129.158.187] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/&&/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/&&/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/&&/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/&&/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/&&/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/&&/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/&&/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "pc9308" from file "/home/&&/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/&&/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
 debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
 debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
 debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
 debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
 debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 124/256
 debug2: bits set: 548/1024
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: RSA &&
 debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "pc9308" from file "/home/&&/.ssh/known_hosts"
 debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/&&/.ssh/known_hosts:11
 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
 debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "&&" from file "/home/&&/.ssh/known_hosts"
 debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/&&/.ssh/known_hosts:12
 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
 debug1: Host '**' is known and matches the RSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /home/&&/.ssh/known_hosts:11
 debug2: bits set: 509/1024
 debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
 debug2: kex_derive_keys
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f6ef8a808b0)
debug2: key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
**@p**'s password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 52 padlen 12 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
**@**'s password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 52 padlen 12 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
**@**'s password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 52 padlen 12 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f6ef8a808b0)
    debug2: key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
    debug2: key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
    debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
    debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
    debug1: No valid Key exchange context
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
    debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
    Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
    Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
    Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/&&/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug3: send_pubkey_test
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/magu_/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup password
    debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    **@p**'s password: 
    debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 52 padlen 12 extra_pad 64)
    debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    Permission denied, please try again.
    **@**'s password: 
    debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 52 padlen 12 extra_pad 64)
    debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    Permission denied, please try again.
    **@**'s password: 
    debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 52 padlen 12 extra_pad 64)
    debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Answer (score 2):

1. check /var/log/auth or /var/log/secure on the remote machine and look for errors or warnings.
2. use ssh -vvv username@server and read the output carefully
3. Make sure you aren't using an allowed user list.
4. Make sure if you are trying to log in as root that the option to allow root login is not disabled.
5. Make sure password authentication is turned on and that a key is not required.

If all else fails print the output of ssh -vvv ....   or any warnings /errors you find in /var/log/auth or /var/log/secure

Comment: Thank's for your offer. I didn't find any of the proposed files in 1.) I did print the output of 2) 3/4) I'm not trying to log in as root